# Sharepoint connected web parts: Automatically refresh 2nd web part when clicking 1st

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, connected-web-parts

I have two connected web parts where I click on one of the 1st hyperlinked column values to filter the 2nd results. This is to filter the results on the 2nd based on my choice in 1st

This works well except that I have to Refresh the 2nd web part to update my result , using refresh button. I want this to update automatically once I click on 1st webpart link , any idea ?

I'm using SharePoint designer 2013.

Comment: Please ask your second question as a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the AJAX options in the web part edit panel. All should be unchecked (and also uncheck the refresk button!). If still not working, please reply here.